# InputAccessoryView's subview toolbar buttons not working

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar, inputaccessoryview

I tried to add two different toolbars to Inputaccessoryview. But InputAccessoryView's subview toolbar buttons not working.

I tried to create 2 seperate uitoolbar and add one of them as inputaccessoryview. Then I added second toolbar as subview. It looks very well but buttons not working, it's just looking in there.

There is my code

```
        let entryToolbar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: -50, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        entryToolbar.barStyle = Theme.barStyle!
        entryToolbar.tintColor = Theme.userColor
        let sendToolbar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: -0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 50))
        sendToolbar.barStyle = Theme.barStyle!
        sendToolbar.tintColor = Theme.userColor

        sendToolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "gönder", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(gonder)),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "vazgeç", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(vazgec))]
        entryToolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "(bkz:)", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(bkz)),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "hede", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(hede)),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "*", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(gizlihede)),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "-spoiler-", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(spoiler)),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "http://", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(link))]
        sendToolbar.sizeToFit()
        sendToolbar.addSubview(entryToolbar)
        entryGir.inputAccessoryView = sendToolbar
```

How can I add multi toolbar as inputaccessoryview and how could it work this buttons?

There is a view of my viewcontroller.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXmGl.png

Comment: A toolbar cannot have another toolbar as a subview. A toolbar cannot have any subviews at all.

Comment: Then how can I add multi toolbars as inputaccessoryview?

Comment: You can’t. But then, your use of a toolbar at all is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add any subviews to `UIToolbar`. What you have to do to make your toolbar as in provided image is: create custom class that extends `UIView`, configure that custom `UIView` UI by code or load it from `NIB` and write all the control logic of buttons and other UI elements in that custom class implementation. Then just use that custom `UIView` as your `inputAccessoryView`.

---

You can get some more information of where to begin with custom `inputAccessoryView` implementation [here](https://medium.com/@thedan84/how-to-set-up-a-keyboard-input-accessory-view-programmatically-4f78f0420351).

Comment: I see. Thank you, I will do that!